# Error launching GRASS GUI : error message related to gcmd.py or gi_set.py

Tags: grass-gis, installation

I am trying to run GRASS GIS for the first time. However, when I try to run GRASS (by clicking on the icon in the start-up menu), I get the following error message:

```
> Starting GRASS GIS... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 43, in
> <module>
>     from core.gcmd import GMessage, GError, DecodeString, RunCommand   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\core\gcmd.py", line
> 43, in <module>
>     from win32file import ReadFile, WriteFile ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. ERROR: Error in GUI
> startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report
> this error to the GRASS developers. On systems with package manager,
> make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui,
> installed. To run GRASS GIS in text mode use the --text flag. Use
> '--help' for further options
>      grass78 --help See also: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/helptext.html Exiting... Press
> any key to continue . . .
```

I am using Windows 10, 64-bit.
I no almost nothing about running code from a console so if that is the solution, please indicate the very first steps.

EDIT: This error is the same as reported by the bug report on `github`: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1218.

Is the solution to install another version of GRASS or wait for an updated version without the bug?

Comment: Please take a look at the instructions here: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7

Comment: At this point, I am just trying to open GRASS (on its own), and failing. I am not using the package `grass7` in R.

Comment: Ok, it seems that you are hit by this error: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1218

Comment: @markusN I install the legacy version  (GRASS 7.6) and it opened as I would expect it to. Thanks for directing me towards the bug.

Comment: I am confident we get it fixed (the bug was just identified)!

Comment: The updated installer (GRASS GIS 7.8.5-2) is now available: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above, the error has been identified (see related [GitHub issue 1218](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1218)). The current (as of today) options are:

- install the previous version 7.8.4 of GRASS GIS and wait for an updated version without the bug
- locally modify the bat file as indicated in the report and fix the path issue in the actually installed version.

I hope that the winGRASS packager can release a new package 7.8.5-2 in the next days.

*Edit: The updated Windows-installer (GRASS GIS 7.8.5-2) is now available: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows/*